# Proving $\displaystyle P(A|B \ \mathrm{and} \ C) = \frac{P(A|C)P(B|A \ \mathrm{and} \ C)}{P(B|C)}$

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Problem**

Prove that $\displaystyle P(A \mid B \cap C) = \frac{P(A\mid C) \cdot P(B\mid A \cap C)}{P(B\mid C)}$.

**Thoughts**

I'm having some trouble interpreting $\displaystyle P(A\mid B  \cap C)$, and whether it means $\displaystyle P((A\mid B)  \cap C)$ or $\displaystyle P(A\mid (B  \cap C))$.

Does the former make sense at all? The probability of (A given B) and C?

And in either case, I don't really know where to start with this one, as I don't know what to assume as given.

It certainly looks like a case of Bayes' theorem, but the second probability in the numberator throws me off.

Comment: Set $P_C(X) = P(X \mid C)$. Rewriting your equation in terms of $P_C$ gives you precisely Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: "Does the former make sense at all? The probability of (A given B) and C?" No it does not since there is no object (and in particular, no event) (A given B).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, $P(A|B\cap C)$ means $P(A|(B\cap C))$.

Then, you can use the definition of conditional probability: $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

LHS: $P(A|B\cap C)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}$

RHS: $\frac{P(A|C)P(B|A\cap C)}{P(B|C)}=\frac{\frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}\frac{P(B\cap A\cap C)}{P(A\cap C)}}{\frac{P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}}=\frac{P(B\cap A\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}$

So, LHS=RHS.

Hope that helps!